didJustFinish never turns false even if the sound is finished playing : React native expo-av
Hello fellow developers,
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with expo-av in my React Native project. Specifically, the didJustFinish property never turns true even after the sound finishes playing. This is quite frustrating as it prevents me from accurately handling playback completion.
I've scoured various resources, including AI tools like ChatGPT and Gemini, but no luck. The consensus often veers towards suggesting a complete shift to React Native CLI and react-native-sound due to reliability concerns with expo-av. However, I'd like to give Expo one last shot before making such a drastic change.
